# Base R: Replacing the horizontal line of median in a boxplot with a horizontal line of mean

Tags: r, visualization

This base R code creates a regular boxplot that shows median as the horizontal line in the box. But is there a way to modify this code, so that the horizontal line would be mean instead of median?

```
a <- df$A
b <- df$B

C <- list(a,b)

names(C) <- c(paste("A"), paste("B"))

par(mgp=c(3,2,0))

y_axis_limits <- c(1, 7)

boxplot(C, col = "red", ylab="value", ylim = y_axis_limits,outline=FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not generally recommend this, but if you *truly* wanted to replace the median with the mean, you could first save a blank plot (below, `xx`) then replace the median stats with the mean, then plot using `bxp`.

Below I made up some data where the mean and median are noticeably different for example purposes:

```
set.seed(123)
a <- rnbinom(1000, mu = 10, size = 0.5)
b <- rnbinom(1000, mu = 10, size = 0.2)

C <- list(a,b)
names(C) <- c("A", "B")
y_axis_limits <- c(0, 25)

# Check what the medians are
unlist(lapply(C, median)) 
# A B 
# 4 1 

xx <- boxplot(C, plot = FALSE)
xx$stats

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  0.0    0 
# [2,]  1.0    0 
# [3,]  4.0    1 # Median <- change this
# [4,] 11.5    8 
# [5,] 27.0   20 

xx$stats[3, ] <- unlist(lapply(C, mean)) #replace median with mean

bxp(xx, boxfill = "red", ylim = y_axis_limits, ylab = "value")
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could add `segments` to the original plot that show the mean along side the median to capture both measures of central tendency:

```
boxplot(C, col = "red", ylab="value", ylim = y_axis_limits,outline=FALSE)

segments(x0 = c(0.6, 1.6), x1 = c(1.4, 2.4), 
         y0 = c(mean(a), mean(b)), lty = 3, col = "purple")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @jpsmith. You are right, it is not a good idea to replace the median line with a mean line